# Не выводится таблица SQLite на сайт, Django

Tags: python, django

Создал таблицу в **models.py**:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
   age = models.IntegerField()
```

после чего в **views.py** добавил:

```
def index(request):
   people Person.objects.all()
   return render(request, "index.html", {"people": people})
```

В шаблоне **index.html** сделал вывод, но он не выводит таблицу. Он вывел "<QuerySet []>"

Comment: А записи в базу добавили? И как вы выводите в `index.html`, циклом?

Comment: Записи добавил SQL-запросами в DB Browser for SQLite. Да, вывожу циклом  {% for person in people %} {{people.id}}{{people.name}} {{people.age}}{endfor}

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

у тебя во view пропущено равно

```
people Person.objects.all()
```

Можно так:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {"people": Person.objects.all()})
```

А еще нужно:

1. В консоли забить python manage.py createsuperuser и ответить на вопросы
2. Зайти по адресу http://127.0.0.1/admin и ввести данные которые ты вводил выше
3. Заполнить данными таблицу people
4. У тебя в комментарии {endfor} а надо {% endfor %}
5. Ещё people на person измени в цикле.

> {% for person in people %}
> {{person.id}}
> {{person.name}}
> {{person.age}}  {% endfor %}